# .htaccess rewrite request from OLD rest endpoint NEW endpoint

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to include in my .htaccess file a condition to rewrite requests to a REST endpoint that will no longer exist after I perform some updates to the location of the new endpoint. The existing request looks something like this:

https://www.example.com/applications/interface/?info&key=xxx&indentifier=xxx

I would like the new request to be similar structure, just in a different location, in the community folder:

https://www.example.com/community/applications/interface/?info&key=xxx&indentifier=xxx

Any help would be greatly appreciated. My existing .htaccess looks like below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.(js|css|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|ico|map)(\?|$) /404error.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you can't just redirect the old request to the new one? Does the URI need to be internally rewritten?

If a redirect is good enough, you can do something like this (note that I'm using mod_rewrite and *not* mod_alias' `Redirect` directive, this is because they both end up getting applied to the same request and may conflict with your existing routing rule)

```
RewriteRule ^applications/interface/$ /community/applications/interface/ [L,R]
```

And you'd want that right under `RewriteBase`. This will take requests that look like `/applications/interface/` and redirect them to `/community/applications/interface/` with all of the query string parameters intact. The regex will only match that URI specifically, with the trailing `/` and as well.

If you need to do some sort of internal rewrite, I'd suggest doing this within your framework instead of trying to use mod_rewrite in the htaccess file. You've got it setup so every request is routed to `index.php` and it's up to that code to figure out what needs to go where.

Comment: This seems to be partly working. When I send the request with the query parameters, it is not rewritten. When I send the request as https://www.example.com/applications/interface/, without any parameters or api method (?info) the request is rewritten and redirected to the correct location.